# Apache mod_proxy_load balancer giving internal 500 error

Tags: mod-proxy, mod-proxy-balancer

I was trying to load balance the requests coming uri `/v1.0/api` to my backend instances using Apache `mod_proxy_load` balancer:

I tried with following configuration:

```
    <Proxy *>
    Require all granted
    </Proxy>

    ProxyPass /v1.0/api/ !
    ProxyPass / balancer://mycluster/ stickysession=BALANCEID nofailover=On
    ProxyPassReverse / https://10.23.45.66:8081/v1.0/api/
    ProxyPassReverse / https://10.23.45.67:8081/v1.0/api/
    <Proxy balancer://mycluster>
      BalancerMember https://10.23.45.66:8081/v1.0/api/ route=http1
      BalancerMember https://10.23.45.67:8081/v1.0/api/ route=http2
    </Proxy>

    <Location /v1.0/api/>
      SetHandler /v1.0/api/
      Require all granted
    </Location>
```

Kindly help me in fixing this problem.

Thanks,
Pradeep

Answer (score 1):

I got it fixed myself.

by enabling few more modules: mod_proxy, mod_proxy_http.

Thanks.

Comment: My problem, too. Thanks.